# galera cluster with mariadb 10.3.13 is not replicating on RHEL 8.1

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera, redhat

I'm installing a galera cluster using mariadb 10.3.13 with two nodes in redhat 8.1 server.
I enabled ports 3306, 4567, 4568 y 4444 ports. selinux is disabled. firewall disabled.
The first node is started by galera_new_cluster. It works.
When I try to start the second node by systemctl start mysql. It delays to finish the process. The data is not replicating but I see no errors.
By tcpdump I see traffic incomming to second node but it's not replicating.

What can I do?

server.cnf configuration:

```
[server]

[mysqld]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://172.24.10.53,172.24.10.54
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
```

mysql_error.log

```
2020-01-30 23:39:37 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: afb4ec56-43e3-11ea-9fc0-c7a8579dc264 from 1 (dbaCluNodo1.pki)
2020-01-30 23:39:37 0 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
    version    = 4,
    component  = PRIMARY,
    conf_id    = 1,
    members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
    act_id     = 0,
    last_appl. = 0,
    protocols  = 0/9/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
    group UUID = 5a3e63d8-43db-11ea-9acf-7a26185f2888
2020-01-30 23:39:37 0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
2020-01-30 23:39:37 0 [Note] WSREP: Trying to continue unpaused monitor
2020-01-30 23:39:37 2 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 5a3e63d8-43db-11ea-9acf-7a26185f2888:0, view# 2: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 1, protocol version 3
2020-01-30 23:39:37 2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2020-01-30 23:39:37 2 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 9 (4, 2)
2020-01-30 23:39:37 2 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 0, protocol version: 4
2020-01-30 23:39:37 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2020-01-30 23:39:39 0 [Note] WSREP: (e88922b7, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
```

Comment: How much data in the dataset?  Are you using "replicate" to indicate the initial cloning of the data from one Galera node to another?  (As opposed to "replication" between a Master and a Slave?)

Comment: 60gb. So I tried uninstalling galera and installed again (fresh installation) to make discards but I have same results. It's delaying.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I know what happened. What I did:

1) vi /etc/selinux/config

2) Change state to from enforcing to disabled

3) Apply init 6 (restart server)